# jQuery Validation improperly true

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I currently have a form that I am validating with the jQuery validator plugin. Within the form, I have one field that will be, depending on the input another field, required or not.

```
 <select name="supportiveServices" id="supportiveServices" style="float: left; margin-left: 20px; width: 30%;">
        <option value="">Select One</option>
        <option value="Accepted">Accepted</option>
        <option value="Declined">Declined</option>
    </select>


 <input name= "serviceStartDate" id= "serviceStartDate" type="date" style="width: 50%;"></input>
```

jQuery

```
 serviceStartDate: {
            required: function(element) {
                 if($("#supportiveServices").val() == 'Accepted') {
                    return true;
                }
                 else {
                    return false;
                 }
            },

        },
```

This dependency requirement seems to work fine but the issue I am consistently running into is I that I need the date to valid as well. I have added a method to ensure dates are valid.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("DateFormat",
    function(value, element) {
    return value.match(/^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/);
 },
  "Please enter a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy";
 );
```

I am new to this plugin but I have tried the following two solutions, both of which return true and require input:

1. Creating a function that basically returns true if the date is empty and false if not.

   ```
   serviceStartDate: {
           required: function(element) {
                if($("#supportiveServices").val() == 'Accepted') {
                   return true;
               }
                else {
                   return false;
                }
           },

           DateFormat: function(element) {
               if($("#serviceStartDate").val() != 0 || $("#serviceStartDate").val() != null || $("#serviceStartDate").val() != undefined || $("#serviceStartDate").val() != '') {
                   return true;
               } else {
                   return false;
               }
           }

       },
   ```
2. Create a separate method.

   ```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("DateFormatSupport",
         function(value, element) {
            if ($("#serviceStartDate") == 0 ) {
            return value.match(/^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/);
          } 
       },
        "Please enter a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy"//removed ;
       );
   ```

and calling it.

```
        serviceStartDate: {
            required: function(element) {
                 if($("#supportiveServices").val() == 'Accepted') {
                    return true;
                }
                 else {
                    return false;
                 }
            },

            DateFormatSupport: true
            }

        },
```

I basically need the validator to ensure that if the client doesn't choose "Accepted" for supportive services, then serviceStartDate can be optional. If "Accepted" for supportive service is chosen, than they will be required to fill in serviceStartDate and the date will need to valid as well. As a precaution, I would like if they filled out anything in serviceStartDate, whether it is optional or not, to be a date - This is going to a database so it has to either be null or a date.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried the `date` rule that is already built into the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like if they filled out anything in `serviceStartDate`, whether it is optional or not, to be a date... Any advice?

You merely need to declare the built-in `date` rule on your date field, while making the `required` rule dependent upon your `select` element as you've already done.  There is no need for a custom rule in this situation.  There's also no need to make the `date` rule conditional as all rules are automatically ignored whenever an *optional* field is left blank.

```
rules: {
    supportiveServices: {
        required: true
    },
    serviceStartDate: {
        required: function(element) {
            return ($("#supportiveServices").val() == 'Accepted') ? true : false;
        },
        date: true
    }
}
```

**Working DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/y1Lytetm/](http://jsfiddle.net/y1Lytetm/)**

**NOTES**:

- I used [ternary shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for your conditional... it's one line of code replacing six.
- There is no such thing as an `input` ***container*** element, so I removed your closing `</input>` tag, which does not exist as valid HTML.